# How to export correctly a Blend4web project?

Tags: blender

I'm trying to export a cow from blender with blend4web the result I get is this:

[cow in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWlM2.jpg)

my problem is with the texture... as you can see in the picture only an half of the cow is ok the other it's just not there...

another problem:  I manage to move the cow inside blender, how can I export the movement of the cow also in browser?   because the cow is motionless now.

any suggestions?
p.s. I'm a beginner to blender so I'm sorry if my explanation is not really clear

Answer (score 0):

seems that you have Mirror modifier. You need either to apply it or to use the option "apply modifiers" under "Export options" tab.

About the animation there may be several issues, please look trough [Documentation of animation](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/animation.html), hope it helps.

Also, feel free to write directly on [B4W forums](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/), you can attach your .blend file here and you will definitely get support there :)